# UiButton + UipickerView Action method not calling all devices (below version of iOS 5)

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

> Hi all i have strange problem with UIPickerview + UIButton.. I have
>   create a project with xcode 4.2. I add UIPickerview with 2 components
>   in 1st component i add a label and 2nd component i add button, on
>   button click i have to go other view  . every thing is working fine in
>   simulator and iOS 5 devices but not working in Devices which have
>   version below iOS 5. My code is here

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIView *tempView;

    if(component==1)
    {
        tempView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,60, 50)]; 
        UIButton *_btnYou=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [_btnYou setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0,55, 50)];
        [_btnYou setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_i.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [_btnYou setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_u.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [_btnYou addTarget:self action:@selector(GoToRegistrationPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [tempView addSubview:_btnYou];
        [_btnYou setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
        return tempView;
        //return  _btnYou;
    }
    else 
    {
        tempView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,168, 50)]; 
        if(!([[dates objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"Today"]||[[dates objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"Idag"])){
            //add days
            UILabel *lab=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 0,54, 50)];
            [lab setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
            [lab setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
            [lab setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
            [lab setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:20]];
            [lab setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20]];
            lab.text=[[[dates objectAtIndex:row] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:0];
            [tempView addSubview:lab];
        }
        //add month

        UILabel *labDate=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(62, 0,106, 50)];
        [labDate setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [labDate setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [labDate setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [labDate setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:25]];
        [labDate setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:25]];
        if(([[dates objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"Today"]||[[dates objectAtIndex:row] isEqualToString:@"Idag"])){
            [labDate setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
            [labDate setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
            labDate.text=[dates objectAtIndex:row]; 
        }else{
            labDate.text=[[[dates objectAtIndex:row] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] objectAtIndex:1];
        }
        [tempView addSubview:labDate];
    }
    return tempView;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
{
    return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
        return [dates count];
    else if(component == 1)
        return 4;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(component == 0)
        return 168.0;
    else if(component == 1)
        return 66.0;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 50.0;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    notificationDate=[dates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]];
    NSLog(@"%@", [dates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]]);
}

-(void)GoToRegistrationPage:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"This is GoToRegistrationPage Button");
}
```

GoToRegistrationPage metod not calling Devices (version

Comment: Check did you add UIPickerViewDelegate and try it..Are you getting any warning about this method??-(void)GoToRegistrationPage:(id)sender

Comment: Objective-c convention: method names should begin in lowercase `GoToRegistrationPage` should be `goToRegistrationPage`

Comment: @R.A i already set delegate and dataSource also

Comment: @Narayana did you implement that GoToRegistrationPage method in your .h file ??

Answer (score 1):

<strike>The problem here is that you aren't retaining your button. The target `self` in `[_btnYou addTarget:self action:@selector(GoToRegistrationPage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];` is not retained. So when _btnYou get's autoreleased, it's target become nil.</strike>

You need to add the button as a retained property of your class, then you can refer to it as self.btnYou and instantiate it like so:

```
self.btnYou = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

In case I am wrong about this retention business, 
I also noticed that you set the selector for  `UIControlEventTouchDown`. Typically, you fire the actions on `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.  Don't know if that will make a difference.

Comment: The button get's retained when it's added as a subview to the tempView.

Comment: Yes the button is retained. But not the target. Check out the docs for UIControl. So as soon as it's autoreleased, it loses the pointer to the target.

Comment: Target is self, why it has to be retained explicitly? And the documentation says it doesn't retains the target.

Comment: I'm sorry, I might be a little too light headed tonight. You may be right. I did have a problem with this before, but perhaps the target was not self in that instance.

Comment: Are using storyboard and ARC in that project??

Comment: Then definitely ignore my retention nonsense

Comment: What's about the storyboard??

Comment: Does anyone think that the button is not getting fired because it is in a pickerview. Perhaps the event is not getting to the button.

Comment: What's about device configuration where it is not running?

Comment: yea.Apple told that it will work on IOS 4.0 upper but I never tested the thing

Answer (score 0):

Most thinking part is that it is running in all places but not running in lower of iOS 5.0 device.

Apple mentioned about ARC that "ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4." please check that also.

I think you are using weak reference for button and it is not supported in iOS 4.0.